# Comparison between prime-count function $\pi(p_n^2)$ and $\frac{\phi{(p_n\#)}}{p_n\#}\cdot p_n^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Looking at the value $\quad\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\log(x)}\quad$ in the table in [Prime-counting_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), I compared the values with those obtained by $\quad\pi(p_n^2)-\frac{\phi{(p_n\#)}}{p_n\#}\cdot p_n^2$

with $\quad\pi()\quad$ prime-counting function,$\quad \#\quad$ primorial and $\quad\phi()\quad$ Euler's totient function.

Here are some values:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   n&    p_n^2& \pi(p_n^2)&         \left\lfloor\frac{\phi{(p_n\#)}}{p_n\#}\cdot p_n^2\right\rfloor&       \pi(p_n^2)-\left\lfloor\frac{\phi{(p_n\#)}}{p_n\#}\cdot p_n^2  \right\rfloor \\ \hline
   1&     4&         2&       2&       0   \\ \hline
   2&     9&         4&       3&       1   \\ \hline
   3&     25&        9&       6&       3   \\ \hline
   4&     49&        15&      11&      4   \\ \hline
   5&     121&       30&      25&      5   \\ \hline
   6&     169&       39&      32&      7   \\ \hline
   7&     289&       61&      52&      9   \\ \hline
   8&     361&       72&      61&      11  \\ \hline
   9&     529&       99&      86&      13  \\ \hline
   10&    841&       146&     132&     14  \\ \hline
   11&    961&       162&     146&     16  \\ \hline
   12&    1369&      219&     203&     16  \\ \hline
   13&    1681&      263&     243&     20  \\ \hline
   14&    1849&      283&     262&     21  \\ \hline
   15&    2209&      329&     306&     23  \\ \hline
   16&    2809&      409&     382&     27  \\ \hline
   17&    3481&      487&     465&     22  \\ \hline
   18&    3721&      519&     489&     30  \\ \hline
   19&    4489&      609&     581&     28  \\ \hline
   20&    5041&      675&     644&     31 \\ \hline 
   21&    5329&      705&     671&     34 \\ \hline 
   22&    6241&      811&     776&     35 \\ \hline 
   23&    6889&      886&     847&     39 \\ \hline 
   24&    7921&      1000&    962&     38 \\ \hline 
   25&    9409&      1163&    1132&    31 \\ \hline 
   26&    10201&     1252&    1215&    37 \\ \hline 
   27&    10609&     1294&    1251&    43 \\ \hline 
   28&    11449&     1381&    1338&    43 \\ \hline 
   29&    11881&     1423&    1375&    48 \\ \hline 
   30&    12769&     1523&    1465&    58 \\ \hline 
&    &    &    &    \\ \hline 
66&    100489&    9631&    9668&   -37 \\ \hline 
&    &    &    &    \\ \hline
169&   1018081&   79830&   82347&  -2517 \\ \hline  
\end{array}

edit: also using the definition for natural numbers of the primorial  by $\quad\pi(m)-\frac{\phi{(\lfloor\sqrt m \rfloor\#)}}{\lfloor\sqrt m \rfloor\#}\cdot m$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   m& \pi(m)&         \left\lfloor\frac{\phi{(\lfloor\sqrt m \rfloor\#)}}{\lfloor\sqrt m \rfloor\#}\cdot m\right\rfloor&       \pi(m)-\left\lfloor\frac{\phi{(\lfloor\sqrt m \rfloor\#)}}{\lfloor\sqrt m \rfloor\#}\cdot m  \right\rfloor \\ \hline
   10&          4&        3&       1   \\ \hline    
   100&         25&        22&    3   \\ \hline    
   1000&        168&       152&       16   \\ \hline   
   10000&       1229&      1203&      26   \\ \hline   
   100000&      9592&      9651&     -59   \\ \hline   
   1000000&     78498&     80965&    -2467   \\ \hline
   10000000&    664579&    696013&   -31434   \\ \hline   
\end{array}

I observed that the difference is smaller than using $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$. There is already a study on this topic, can you point me to some articles?

Comment: What is $P_n^2$? The $n^{\text{th}}$ prime squared? Why not plug in the best known asymptomatic for these constants and calculate the error term? I don't see why there would exist articles for this particular expression.

Comment: @EthanSplaver Yes, is the $n^{th}$ prime squared

Comment: In response to the reason for using this expression, it is due to the fact that fixed $\lfloor\sqrt m\rfloor\#$ there are $\phi(\lfloor\sqrt m\rfloor\#)$ numbers $<\lfloor\sqrt m\rfloor\#$ not multiples of prime numbers less than $\sqrt m$ the formula is therefore obtained considering the percentage $\frac{m}{\lfloor\sqrt m\rfloor\#}$